# How to protect MySQL Data from decompilers?

Tags: java, mysql, security, decompiling

I am creating an application that needs access to a MySQL Database. But I know that people are able to decompile Java code. I am wondering if there is a really secure way for me to connect to my database without it being accessed by decompilers?

Comment: Does that mean you have your username and password hard coded into your code?  Can you describe a bit more of your overall architecture?

Comment: "secure way ... to connect to mysql database" ... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html

Comment: @stdunbar Yes, that is what I mean. I am trying to get around it being hard-coded into it though.

Comment: See the answer from @duskwuff below - in general you'll need to split up your application to do this successfully.

Comment: Your database should not be accessible via the internet, period.  Your clients should not be able to connect directly to your database, period.

Answer (score 4):

In short: no. If you distribute an application which connects to a MySQL server, it will always be possible for users to decompile and/or debug your client application to extract the credentials the application uses to connect.

MySQL is primarily intended for use by a trusted server-side application. If you cannot fully trust your client application (and the users who have access to it!), do not allow the application to connect to your MySQL server. Instead, consider building an HTTP-based API (i.e, a web application) to allow your client software to perform appropriate operations on the database.

Answer (score 0):

In a JavaEE application you can store the data source in the application and configure the connection in your application server.

Is your application a standalone Java application that your users have access to but has access to the Internet? In that case you may consider isolating your data layer to another application stored elsewhere and accessible with a web service, for example.